# How can succinylcholine cause myorelaxation?

Tags: human-biology, physiology, pharmacology

I first thought that this is because of prolonged depolarisations. 
However, I am not sure anymore, because after reading [PubChem](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/suxamethonium#section=DrugBank-Interactions), the only possible pathways are are Choline agonist. 
So I would say that succinylcholine cause myorelaxation by some cholino-receptor agonists. 
I do not think it is about depolarisation and how long it is.

**How can succinylcholine cause myorelaxation?**

Answer (score 3):

Succinycholine, as its name might suggest, is a cholinergic agonist indeed. It acts on the neural plate of skeletal muscles, where it activates the muscle cholinergic receptors.

Phase 1 block due to succinylcholine thus occurs by activating so many receptors at once, that the whole muscle gets desensitized and therefore paralyzed. A corollary of that is that muscle will twitch during activation, thus accounting for the reason why people twitch shortly before becoming paralyzed after a succinycholine iv injection. This phase 1 block will resolve in 2-5 minutes.

Now an interesting phenomenon is that if you go on stimulating the muscle with more cholinergic agonists (for example, a second iv dose of succinylcholine), you may end up provoking endocytosis and degradation of the cholinergic receptors. This is called phase 2 block, and in contrast to phase 1, it will take at least several hours to resolve. This is why we never use a second dose in the clinics, except in very special cases.
You can also read about it all on [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suxamethonium_chloride)

Comment: What is the event called that causes such a phenomena as phase 1 block and phase 2 block? Do other adrenoergic drugs and Cardiac drugs have such characteristics? How such an event documented for instance in PubChem, for instance in the link in the body of my question? I want to be aware of such events for each drug.

Comment: So the short answer to my question is that the succinylcholine cause myorelaxation because of cholino-receptor antagonism with big dose or second dose; stimulated by endocytes and degradation of the cholinergic receptors.

Comment: NOT THAT KIND OF CHOLINERGIC RECEPTOR!!! think autonomic nervous system, not autonomic nervous system... he is talking about nicotinic cholinergic receptor on the SKELETAL MUSCLE, not the muscarinic cholinergic receptors on cardiac conducting cells and muscle... this is a drug to temporarily paralyze the skeletal muscle for the sake of the surgeon doing the operation.. this is an anesthesia drug, not a cardiology drug...

Comment: secondly, this phase 1  vs phase 2 is to distinguish it from the curare-derived neuromuscular blockers which ONLY act as antagonists on the nicotinic cholinergic receptor (aka exhibit phase 2 type effects)... the phase-1/phase-2 type drugs are called depolarizing neuromuscular blockers... the curare derrived ones are nondepolarizing... here is an article listing more depolarizing types with this phase-1/phase2 type effects: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuromuscular-blocking_drug#Depolarizing_blocking_agents another example of a drug is Decamethonium

Comment: I see what your saying, masi... the downregulation of receptors that are overstimulated is pretty common throughout pharmacology, and upregulation with blocking a receptor... for example (1) the dopamine receptor is up/down regulated with levodopa/carbidopa and it causes cycling... in typical psychotics it causes extrapyramidal symptoms... (2) it's also a proposed mechanism of the SSRIs, downregulating the seratonin receptor is what mediates the antidepressant action, supposedly... (3) also thats why going off of a betablocker quickly is very dangerous for patients... the list goes on...

Comment: oops, for "typical psychotics" it's supposed to say "typical ANTIpsychotics"...

Comment: @JasandPruski Please, make your comments an answer, since they are good and make sense.

Comment: @Masi Actually, those comments you propose to turn into an answer do not directly answer your primary question, even if they are good comments. On the other hand, I did answer your primary question and you did not mark it as accepted... just saying :-)

Comment: @Raoul The reason is that I am not satisfied enough. It seems too be too much cardiac. I may be wrong. I need something more etc references, images or anything so that I can be certain about your answer. You have now only a reference to Wikipedia which is not enough. I want to understand this topic.

Comment: @Raoul don't be upset with Masi, he is notoriously finicky... he once down voted a 1 page length answer I posted (which in ym opinion was very good) because it didn't please him... Masi simply wants to learn more and sometimes it's hard to say what he wants to learn... though his questions may be off beat and poorly worded I still feel there is a thread of insight, which always attracts me to them...

Comment: I think Masi's question was this: how is it possible for us to have a drug where the mechanism of the drug is to cause the opposite of what it actively does? the answer: to exhaust the receptor or maybe downregulation of receptors

Comment: @jasand well I'm not upset. It was just a remark. I'm not that eager for fame and reputation.

Comment: @jasand oh, and BTW both elements you cite are in my answer 

Comment: I think he wanted to hear about SSRIs, Parkinson med cycling, extra pyramidal symptoms, etc... As I understand it tolerance can be more tricky... Thats it